# Mystery connector search

Tags: woodworking, shelving, connectors

To fix a bookcase built by my dad who died last year, I am looking for the nylon or plastic connector that he used. They consist of a threaded dowel 3” by1/2” and threaded inserts 1”-wide insert for the 1/2”-threaded nut.  They works really well making bookshelves with the inserts in the shelf boards and in the spindles.  However, I have been unable to find anywhere.

Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: If you can't find what you really want, I suspect you could replace all that with 1/4-20 insert nuts (https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/hardware/fasteners/quick-connect-hardware/44236-1-4-20-quick-connect-plain-insert-nuts) and threaded rod.

Comment: Thanks, Aloysius. I looked, but the size of the hole in the existing threaded insert (9/16") is too large for the the brass or steel inserts that I could find. To work, I need an insert that inserts into the existing plastic/nylon threaded insert.

Comment: Fair enough. There are bigger insert nuts out there... https://www.amazon.com/Z-Threaded-Insert-Internal-Threads/dp/B0026GZU0Q for example

Answer (score 1):

I would call those fluted dowel pins. I use a similar style of pre made dowels. Finding that exact model may take some time but give fluted dowel pins or rods and that should get you close.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ed. The pins are fluted, but the key is that they are also threaded. There are about 5 threads per inch. They screw into the matching threaded inserts. When I search for fluted dowel pins or rods, I just get the wood ones designed to hold glue.

Comment: Is it possible that he threaded them?  I see what you are saying with the angled “threads” they may be OEM but try adding threaded to fluted or a variation of that measurement of the length and threads per inch or mm may be a standard pitch like 1/4-20 or 1/2-12 the diameter and how many Threads per inch. 5 per inch is not a common pitch I am aware of.